# Different reputation count on area51

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51, flair

I noticed that my flair on Area51 gives a different reputation for stackoverflow than my generic flair on stackexchange. This behaviour has been stable for several days. I suspect that the Area51 flair shows the peak reputation (some reputation was migrated with a question answered to another stackexchange site).

Should this be so? Is my interpretation (peak reputation) correct?

Comment: Not peak, just sum of reputation in all sites where you have 200+

Comment: It would be really appreciable if you add your flair, screenshots, and more data. I just dug in your profile(s) for ten minutes, and found that for some reason you have 198 rep on SO, and no negative rep changes, while your Area51 rep shows 209 rep. Agreed that it seems a lot like a bug though.

Comment: @Sha they currently have 198 rep on SO, which shouldn't show up in Area51.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M well, the tooltip on Area51 showing OP here with 209 rep on Stack Overflow, so it means something was deleted, removing some rep but never synchronizing with Area51.

Comment: Today, my rep count on Area51 is in synch with the other counts (200)